# How to compare two tables and to insert value in table A after comparision

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to compare two tables if there is any extra value in table B,if yes then it should be inserted in table A

How to do it in most effective way

Table A

```
Column A Column B  Column Flag
Maths      John     Y
Science    John     Y
English  George     Y
```

Table B

```
Column A  Column B
Maths      John
Science    John
English  George
Japanese George
```

Comment: What is your metric for _most_ effective way? What was ineffective about what you tried? If `'Japanese', 'George'` was inserted in `A` from `B` what be the value of `Flag` for that row? Do you want to compare tables `A` and `B`, or is there some other table you want to compare to `B`? How do you handle duplicate rows in a single table?

Comment: [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)?

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as(
Select B.*
From TableB B
Left Join TableA A
    On A.[Column A] = B.[Column A]
    And A.[Column B] = B.[Column B]
Where NULLIF(A.[Column A], '') Is Null)

Insert Into TableA([Column A], [Column B], [Column Flag])
Select*, null -- or assign whatever value you want to column 3
From cte
```

Comment: Hey loldude, thanks for your answer. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. While your code may answer the question, good posts explain **why/how** this addresses the problem.